# gem5: RuntimeError: Cycle found in configuration hierarchy

Tags: gem5

I'm working on a Processing-in-Memory Simulation by gem5.

I try to link the PIM modules that I made, however, a runtime error with "Cycle found in configuration hierarchy happens".

I do not know when this configuration hierarchy error happens exactly & how to solve it.

I read configuration hierarchy document from gem5 documentation web page several times,

but I couldn't understand how to order the initializations of modules and port bindings to avoid this error.

Also, I don't know how to find the exact code that generates the configuration hierarchy cycle error.

All I can get is just tracebacks of python codes.

If you want to know the configuration code, see the following "very complicated" code from MemConfig.py & traceback.

```
_kernel = PIMMatrix()
_kernel.bridge.num_bridges = 2
_kernel.bridge.slave[0] = _kernel.xbar.master[0]
_kernel.bridge.master[0] = xbar.slave
_kernel.bridge.slave[1] = xbar.master
_kernel.bridge.master[1] = _kernel.xbar.slave[0]

_kernel.row_sched.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[1]
_kernel.row_sched.cmdPort = _kernel.xbar.slave[1]

_kernel.prefix.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[2]
for i in range(16):
    _kernel.prefix.memPort[i] = _kernel.xbar.slave[2 + i]

_kernel.A_row_scratch.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[3]
_kernel.A_row_scratch.seqPort = _kernel.xbar.slave[18]
_kernel.B_row_scratch.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[4]
_kernel.B_row_scratch.seqPort = _kernel.xbar.slave[19]
_kernel.C_row_scratch.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[5]
_kernel.C_row_scratch.seqPort = _kernel.xbar.slave[20]
_kernel.C_int_scratch.instrPort = _kernel.xbar.master[6]
_kernel.C_int_scratch.seqPort = _kernel.xbar.slave[21]

num_row_accs = 8
_kernel.num_accs = num_row_accs
row_accs = []
for i in range(num_row_accs):
    row_acc = PIMRowAccelerator()
    num_colrow_accs = 8
    row_acc.num_accs = num_colrow_accs

    row_acc.bridge.num_bridges = 17
    row_acc.bridge.master[0] = row_acc.xbar.slave[0]


    for j in range(16):
        row_acc.bridge.slave[1 + j] = row_acc.xbar.master[j]

        row_acc.colRowSched.instrPort = row_acc.xbar.master[16]
        row_acc.colRowSched.memPort = row_acc.xbar.slave[1]
        row_acc.sorter.instrPort = row_acc.xbar.master[17]
        for j in range(16):
            row_acc.sorter.memPort = row_acc.xbar.slave[2 + j]
        row_acc.ind_hash.instrPort = row_acc.xbar.master[18]
        row_acc.ind_hash.seqPort = row_acc.xbar.slave[18]
        row_acc.val_hash.instrPort = row_acc.xbar.master[19]
        row_acc.val_hash.seqPort = row_acc.xbar.slave[19]

        colrow_accs = []

        for j in range(num_colrow_accs):
            colrow_acc = PIMColRowAcc()
            num_col_accs = 8
            colrow_acc.num_hashers = 8

            colrow_acc.bridge.num_bridges = 17

            colrow_acc.bridge.master[0] = colrow_acc.xbar.slave[0]
            for k in range(16):
                colrow_acc.bridge.slave[1 + k] = colrow_acc.xbar.master[k]

                colrow_acc.colSched.instrPort = colrow_acc.xbar.master[16]
                colrow_acc.colSched.memPort = colrow_acc.xbar.slave[1]

                hashers = []

                for k in range(num_col_accs):
                    hasher = PIMMulHasher()
                    hasher.instrPort = colrow_acc.xbar.master[17 + k]
                    hasher.memPort = colrow_acc.xbar.slave[2 + k]
                    hashers.append(hasher)
                colrow_acc.hashers = hashers

                colrow_accs.append(colrow_acc)

            row_acc.accs = colrow_accs

            for j in range(num_colrow_accs):
                row_acc.accs[j].bridge.slave[0] = row_acc.xbar.master[20 + j]
                for k in range(16):
                    row_acc.accs[j].bridge.master[1 + k] = row_acc.xbar.slave[20 + 16 * j + k]

            for j in range(16):
                row_acc.ind_hash.memPort[j] = row_acc.xbar.master[28 + j]
            for j in range(16):
                row_acc.val_hash.memPort[j] = row_acc.xbar.master[44 + j]

            row_accs.append(row_acc)
        _kernel.row_accs = row_accs

        for i in range(num_row_accs):
            _kernel.row_accs[i].bridge.slave[0] = _kernel.xbar.master[7 + i]
            for j in range(16):
                _kernel.row_accs[i].bridge.master[1 + j] = _kernel.xbar.slave[22 + 16 * i + j]

        for i in range(16):
            _kernel.cache.pim_side[i] = _kernel.xbar.master[15 + i]
        _kernel.cache.mem_side = _kernel.xbar.slave[150]

        for i in range(16):
            _kernel.A_row_scratch.memPort[i] = _kernel.xbar.master[31 + i]
            _kernel.B_row_scratch.memPort[i] = _kernel.xbar.master[47 + i]
            _kernel.C_row_scratch.memPort[i] = _kernel.xbar.master[63 + i]
            _kernel.C_int_scratch.memPort[i] = _kernel.xbar.master[79 + i]

        pim_kernerls.append(_kernel)
    system.pim_kernerls = pim_kernerls
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/X86/python/m5/main.py", line 457, in main
    exec(filecode, scope)
  File "configs/example/se.py", line 288, in <module>
    Simulation.run(options, root, system, FutureClass)
  File "/mnt/d/gem5/configs/common/Simulation.py", line 614, in run
    m5.instantiate(checkpoint_dir)
  File "build/X86/python/m5/simulate.py", line 120, in instantiate
    for obj in root.descendants(): obj.createCCObject()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1648, in createCCObject
    self.getCCParams()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1589, in getCCParams
    value = value.getValue()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/params.py", line 254, in getValue
    return [ v.getValue() for v in self ]
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1652, in getValue
    return self.getCCObject()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1630, in getCCObject
    params = self.getCCParams()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1589, in getCCParams
    value = value.getValue()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1652, in getValue
    return self.getCCObject()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1630, in getCCObject
    params = self.getCCParams()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1589, in getCCParams
    value = value.getValue()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1652, in getValue
    return self.getCCObject()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1630, in getCCObject
    params = self.getCCParams()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1589, in getCCParams
    value = value.getValue()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/params.py", line 254, in getValue
    return [ v.getValue() for v in self ]
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1652, in getValue
    return self.getCCObject()
  File "build/X86/python/m5/SimObject.py", line 1634, in getCCObject
    % self.path())
RuntimeError: system.pim_kernerls: Cycle found in configuration hierarchy.
```

Comment: Also, the xbar objects are not default crossbars from gem5. It's custom noncoherent crossbar that uses different algorithm for forwarding each received packet. It does not uses address ranges for forwarding. Therefore, I need specify how to link specific master & slave port with array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error. I just found some of my custom modules are referencing system as parameter. This makes a configuration hierarchy cycle. Use --pdb option to debug python code.